# How can I stop Bootstrap offcanvas from scrolling the website

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

I am using a Bootstrap offcanvas for a `<nav>` menu for a mobile site. The goal of the menu is that when the user clicks the `<li>` that it scrolls them down to that section of the website. I created a simply js script that clicks the offcanvas exit button, then uses an ID to scroll the user to that section of the website. The issue is that the offcanvas then scrolls the website back to its own location.

It does do what I need up until the point where the button either focus's itself again or something else is fired which causes the site to scroll back to the top where the button is located.

I looked into it and have read that Bootstrap adds a open-modal class to the body when you use their modals and I assume its a similar class when you use their offcanvas and this will remove the scrollbar and that can affect it. I also see that you shoudl remove the `data-bs-toggle="offcanvas"` if you are using a js script to create the elements, but I am not. How can I achieve this effect on the site? Below is the JS file and the html for the `<nav>`.

JAVASCRIPT:

```js
function ServicePackages(){
    const exitBtn = document.getElementById('button-close');

    exitBtn.click();

    window.location.href = "#service-packages";   
}

function IndividualServices(){
    const exitBtn = document.getElementById('button-close');

    exitBtn.click();

    window.location.href = "#individual-services";
}

function SuspensionSetup(){
    const exitBtn = document.getElementById('button-close');

    exitBtn.click();

    window.location.href = "#suspension-setup";
}

function RacePrepPackages(){
    const exitBtn = document.getElementById('button-close');

    exitBtn.click();

    window.location.href = "#race-prep-packages";
}

function Contact(){
    const exitBtn = document.getElementById('button-close');

    exitBtn.click();

    window.location.href = "#contact";
}

function Home(){
    const exitBtn = document.getElementById('button-close');

    exitBtn.click();

    window.location.href = "#home";
}
```

HTML:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-light">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="javascript: return false">
                <img class="d-inline-block align-text-bottom" src="assets/logo.png" width="156px" height="45px">
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#navModal"
                aria-controls="offcanvasRight">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="offcanvas offcanvas-end" tabindex="-1" id="navModal" aria-labelby="offcanvasRightLabel">
                <div class="offcanvas-header">
                    <img class="offcanvas-title d-inline-block align-text-bottom" src="assets/logo.png" width="156px"
                        height="45px">
                    <button id="button-close" class="btn-close" type="button" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas"
                        aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="offcanvas-body">
                    <script src="modal.js"></script>
                    <ul class="navbar-nav justify-content-end flex-grow-1 pe-3">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" onclick="ServicePackages()" aria-current="page"
                                href="#service-packages">SERVICE
                                PACKAGES</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" onclick="IndividualServices()" aria-current="page"
                                href="#individual-services">INDIVIDUAL
                                SERVICES</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" onclick="SuspensionSetup()" aria-current="page"
                                href="#suspension-setup">SUSPENSION
                                SETUP</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" onclick="RacePrepPackages()" aria-current="page"
                                href="#race-prep-packages">RACE PREP
                                PACKAGES</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" onclick="Contact()" aria-current="page" href="#contact">CONTACT</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link active" onclick="Home()" aria-current="page" href="#home">HOME</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Also I have same problem with offcanvas .With an album page. An album page could be have a very long height . When we click an item of offcanvas , the scrolling to top page is fired and this issue is not solved for me until this date !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bootstrap 5 offcanvas scrolls back to top on close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67383776/bootstrap-5-offcanvas-scrolls-back-to-top-on-close)

Answer (score 0):

first i would try to remove `window.location.href =` from all the functions simply because the href's are already associated to the anchor tag in the HTML.

If that doesn't do anything, I would try to suppress the overflow by adding this to head of document:

```
<style>
  body {overflow:hidden}
</style>
```

Comment: Applied these two corrections and unfortunately the issue persists. I am currently learning Bootstrap and my method of importing is simply by calling the link in the script. It might be more useful if I look into installing the sass files that comes with Bootstrap and trying to debug through the file to see where the breadcrumbs lead to.

Comment: I have same problem with bootstrap 5.2 offcanvas. Do you solve your problem?